# How to create a YES/NO confirmation prompt before executing a copy script?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not good with JavaScript but my boss is requesting a confirmation prompt for a simple tool I made.

I have here the scripts, but I don't know how to put it together so that it can work.

There's a `textarea`, a `button` to copy the text from the `textarea`, and 3 different scripts to create a confirmation prompt before copying the text. If yes, copy the notes. If no, let them finish their notes (do nothing)...

Here's [a demo on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmoxknud/)

The first script I have is this. This is already working whenever it is clicked.

```
function copy1() {
let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
textarea.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

But I need to add a prompt to create a confirmation, and here's the script for that:

```
document.getElementById("promptconfirm").onclick = function() {
confirm("Are you done reviewing your notes?");
};
```

Now I need an if else script (which is still flawed)

```
if (confirm('Are you done reviewing your notes?')) {

console.log('Please try to review your notes before copying.');
} else {

console.log('Please try to review your notes before copying.');
}
```

Now here are the HTMLs

```
<button class="cbtn" title="Copy to Clipboard" id="promptconfirm" onclick="copy1()"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i> Copy</button>

<textarea class="lined" id="textarea1" name="textarea1" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Write something here..." onpaste="console.log('onpastefromhtml')"></textarea>
```

I apologize for asking this kind of help. I cannot find any other combination of this sort.

and thank you in advance..

```js
document.getElementById("promptconfirm").onclick = function() {
confirm("Are you done reviewing your notes?");
};
        
if (confirm('Are you done reviewing your notes?')) {

console.log('Please try to review your notes before copying.');
} else {

console.log('Please try to review your notes before copying.');
}

function copy1() {
let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
textarea.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<button class="cbtn" title="Copy to Clipboard" id="promptconfirm" onclick="copy1()"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i> Copy</button>

<textarea class="lined" id="textarea1" name="textarea1" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Write something here..." onpaste="console.log('onpastefromhtml')"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you mean this:

```js
function copy1() {
  let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

document.getElementById("promptconfirm").onclick = function() {
  if (confirm('Are you done reviewing your notes?')) {
    copy1();
  } else {
    alert('Please try to review your notes before copying.');
  }
};
```

```html
<button class="cbtn" title="Copy to Clipboard" id="promptconfirm" onclick="copy1()"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i> Copy</button>

<textarea class="lined" id="textarea1" name="textarea1" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Write something here..." onpaste="console.log('onpastefromhtml')"></textarea>
```

Write to me in the comments, it suits you, if not, why not.

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke `copy1` if the result of `confirm` is `true`.

```js
document.getElementById("promptconfirm").onclick = function() {
  if(confirm("Are you done reviewing your notes?")){
    copy1();
  } else {
    console.log('Please try to review your notes before copying.');
  }
};

function copy1() {
  let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<button class="cbtn" title="Copy to Clipboard" id="promptconfirm" onclick="copy1()"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i> Copy</button>

<textarea class="lined" id="textarea1" name="textarea1" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Write something here..." onpaste="console.log('onpastefromhtml')"></textarea>
```

Comment: Wow thank you for helping me with this! That's perfect already as it is. But if I may ask for one tiny thing, how can I tweak the buttons of the prompt, so that it's Yes or No instead of Ok and Cancel? If it's too much to ask, this is already enough!

Comment: @TheAuthor `confirm` is completely implemented by the browser, so we cannot change it.

Comment: Alrighty, I understand that. This will work perfectly now. Thank you again, so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since `execCommand` is obsolete, here's what I'd recommend:

```js
document.getElementById("promptconfirm").addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(confirm("Are you done reviewing your notes?")){
    const textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
    const text = textarea.value;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  }
})
```

```html
<button class="cbtn" title="Copy to Clipboard" id="promptconfirm"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i> Copy</button>

<textarea class="lined" id="textarea1" name="textarea1" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Write something here..." onpaste="console.log('onpastefromhtml')"></textarea>
```